# Problems making an Image Gallery using ImageView's and touchesBegan

Tags: ios, objective-c, imageview

I'm trying to create an image gallery for my iPhone app. I have laid out the imageViews and I want them to increase in size when the user clicks on them, and then return to normal when they release. The code I have made works for the first image, but the rest are totally unresponsive. Even if I remove the first one completely.

Here is the code I have been trying to use, does anyone have any ideas as to why it might not be working?

Thanks!

```
- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
if ([touch view] == _imageOne)
{
CGRect newFrame = _imageOne.frame;
newFrame.size.width += 280;
newFrame.size.height += 280;
_imageOne.frame = newFrame;
}
if ([touch view] == _imageTwo)
{
    CGRect newFrame2 = _imageTwo.frame;
    newFrame2.size.width += 280;
    newFrame2.size.height += 280;
    _imageTwo.frame = newFrame2;
}
}

- (void) touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
if ([touch view] == _imageOne)
{
    CGRect newFrame = _imageOne.frame;
    newFrame.size.width -= 280;
    newFrame.size.height -= 280;
    _imageOne.frame = newFrame;
}
if ([touch view] == _imageTwo)
{
    CGRect newFrame2 = _imageTwo.frame;
    newFrame2.size.width -= 280;
    newFrame2.size.height -= 280;
    _imageTwo.frame = newFrame2;
}
}
```

Comment: Are you using autolayout?

Comment: Im not too sure to be honest! I cant seem to find it on right hand side